# exhaustedResultSet even though resultSet is far from exhausted

Tags: java, jdbc

Below is essentially my code.The SQL appears to be working because the call to getFetchSize is returning 10. The call to next() is giving false. If getObject is called it throws an exhaustedResultSet SQLException.This is in a Maven project using Spring to create a REST webservice running in win7 on Tomcat 8.5 with an Oracle 11g DB if any of that matters. Let me know if I'm leaving anything important out.

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

class StringGettingClass {
    public String[] methodToGetStrings() {
        String qry = "SELECT Column FROM TABLE";
        String[] string_array;
       try {
           Context envCtx = (Context) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env");
           DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/JdbcDb");
           Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
           Statement s = connection.createStatement();
           ResultSet r = s.executeQuery(qry);
           int rows = r.getFetchSize();
           string_array = new String[rows];
           int row = 0;
           while (r.next()) {
                string_array[row] = r.getObject("Column").toString();
                row++;
           }
       } catch (SQLException s) {
           s.printStacktrace();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return string_array;
    }
}
```

Comment: `getFetchSize` does not return the number of resulting records, it indicates (an hint to the jdbc driver of) the size of records returned for each database conversation

Comment: I don't know what database you use. But why use keywords like `TABLE`? Couldn't you find better names for your tables and columns?

Comment: If `next()` returns `false`, there are no more rows, if you then still try to retrieve a column value, then the exception is correct. In other words: the problem you think you have is not a problem, it is the expected and correct behavior.

Comment: ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ Is there a command to get the number of resulting records? I'll look again, but I couldn't find one. What is being sent back if not a record?

ujulu I am using Oracle 11g. I am paranoid and try to genericise my code as much as possible before posting.

MarkThe query itself seems to work when I run it directly.